# extract data from ovs dump-flow using pyparsing

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyparsing, openvswitch

I'm trying to extract source and destination MAC and IP addresses and packets transmitted from the output of the command "ovs dump-flows". The output of the command will be as follows

```
in_port(2),eth(src=00:26:55:e8:b0:43,dst=bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc),eth_type(0x0806),arp(sip=193.170.192.129,tip=193.170.192.142,op=2,sha=00:26:55:e8:b0:43,tha=bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc), packets:0, bytes:0, used:never, actions:1
in_port(2),eth(src=bc:30:5b:f6:dd:fc,dst=bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc),eth_type(0x0800),ipv4(src=193.170.192.143,dst=193.170.192.142,proto=6,tos=0,ttl=64,frag=no),tcp(src=45969,dst=5672), packets:1, bytes:87, used:4.040s, flags:P., actions:1
in_port(2),eth(src=bc:30:5b:f6:dd:fc,dst=bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc),eth_type(0x0800),ipv4(src=193.170.192.143,dst=193.170.192.142,proto=6,tos=0,ttl=64,frag=no),tcp(src=45992,dst=5672), packets:118412, bytes:21787661, used:2.168s, flags:P., actions:1
in_port(2),eth(src=00:18:6e:3a:aa:e8,dst=01:80:c2:00:00:00), packets:29131, bytes:1864384, used:1.200s, actions:drop
```

The code is

```
from pyparsing import *
import datetime,time
import os
f = os.popen('ovs-dpctl dump-flows ovs-system')
flows = f.read()
print "Flows are ", flows

LBRACE,RBRACE,COMMA,EQUAL,COLON = map(Suppress,'(),=:')
in_port = packets = proto = tos = ttl = src = dst = op = Word(nums)
ipAddress = Combine(Word(nums) + ('.' + Word(nums))*3)
twohex = Word(hexnums,exact=2)
macAddress = Combine(twohex + (':'+twohex)*5)
eth_type = Combine('0x' + Word(hexnums,exact=4))
frag = Word

flowTcp = "in_port" + LBRACE + in_port("in_port") + RBRACE + COMMA + "eth" + LBRACE + "src" + EQUAL + macAddress("src") + COMMA + "dst" + EQUAL + macAddress("dst") + RBRACE + COMMA + "eth_type" + LBRACE + eth_type("eth_type") + RBRACE + COMMA + "ipv4" + LBRACE + "src" + EQUAL + ipAddress("src") + COMMA + "dst" + EQUAL + ipAddress("dst") + COMMA + "proto" + EQUAL + proto("proto") + COMMA + "tos" + EQUAL + tos("tos") + COMMA + "ttl" + EQUAL + ttl("ttl") + COMMA + "frag" + EQUAL + frag("frag") + RBRACE + COMMA + "tcp" + LBRACE + "src" + EQUAL + src("srcPkt") + COMMA + "dst" + EQUAL + dst("dstPkt") + RBRACE + "packets" + COLON + packets("packets")
```

Since the name representations for Mac address, IP address and packets is same as "src" and "dst". I'm not able to parse and extract the required data because of reoccuring names. 
Please suggest on how this can be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I had to reformat your code, so that I could more easily see the structure in the parser:

```
flowTcp = ("in_port" + LBRACE + in_port("in_port") + RBRACE + COMMA + 
            "eth" + LBRACE + "src" + EQUAL + macAddress("src") + COMMA + 
            "dst" + EQUAL + macAddress("dst") + RBRACE + COMMA + 
            "eth_type" + LBRACE + eth_type("eth_type") + RBRACE + COMMA + 
            "ipv4" + LBRACE + "src" + EQUAL + ipAddress("src") + COMMA + 
                "dst" + EQUAL + ipAddress("dst") + COMMA + 
                "proto" + EQUAL + proto("proto") + COMMA + 
                "tos" + EQUAL + tos("tos") + COMMA + 
                "ttl" + EQUAL + ttl("ttl") + COMMA + 
                "frag" + EQUAL + frag("frag") + RBRACE + COMMA + 
            "tcp" + LBRACE + 
                "src" + EQUAL + src("srcPkt") + COMMA + 
                "dst" + EQUAL + dst("dstPkt") + 
                RBRACE + 
            "packets" + COLON + packets("packets"))
```

Then, to parse the examples that you posted, I had to make some of these structures Optional, and add the missing "eth" and "arp" fields (and fix your definition of `frag`):

```
frag = oneOf("yes no")
flowTcp = ("in_port" + LBRACE + in_port("in_port") + RBRACE + COMMA + 
            "eth" + LBRACE + 
                "src" + EQUAL + macAddress("src") + COMMA + 
                "dst" + EQUAL + macAddress("dst") + 
                RBRACE + COMMA + 
            Optional("eth_type" + LBRACE + eth_type("eth_type") + RBRACE + COMMA) +
            Optional("arp" + LBRACE +
                "sip" + EQUAL + ipAddress("sip") + COMMA +
                "tip" + EQUAL + ipAddress("tip") + COMMA +
                "op" + EQUAL + op("op") + COMMA + 
                "sha" + EQUAL + macAddress("sha") + COMMA + 
                "tha" + EQUAL + macAddress("tha") + 
                RBRACE + COMMA) +
            Optional("ipv4" + LBRACE + 
                "src" + EQUAL + ipAddress("src") + COMMA + 
                "dst" + EQUAL + ipAddress("dst") + COMMA + 
                "proto" + EQUAL + proto("proto") + COMMA + 
                "tos" + EQUAL + tos("tos") + COMMA + 
                "ttl" + EQUAL + ttl("ttl") + COMMA + 
                "frag" + EQUAL + frag("frag") + 
                RBRACE + COMMA) +
            Optional("tcp" + LBRACE + 
                "src" + EQUAL + src("srcPkt") + COMMA + 
                "dst" + EQUAL + dst("dstPkt") + 
                RBRACE) +
            "packets" + COLON + packets("packets"))
```

At this point, the parser "works", but it has the problem you have asked about, which is that you have repeated use of some results names, like "src", "dst", and so on.

Obviously, you could just use different names, like "eth_src", "tcp_src". But I suggest you use pyparsing `Group` classes to add structure to your parsed data. I took each of the substructures out to define as their own mini-parser:

```
eth = Group("eth" + LBRACE + 
                "src" + EQUAL + macAddress("src") + COMMA + 
                "dst" + EQUAL + macAddress("dst") + 
                RBRACE)
arp = Group("arp" + LBRACE +
                "sip" + EQUAL + ipAddress("sip") + COMMA +
                "tip" + EQUAL + ipAddress("tip") + COMMA +
                "op" + EQUAL + op("op") + COMMA + 
                "sha" + EQUAL + macAddress("sha") + COMMA + 
                "tha" + EQUAL + macAddress("tha") + 
                RBRACE)
ipv4 = Group("ipv4" + LBRACE + "src" + EQUAL + ipAddress("src") + COMMA + 
                "dst" + EQUAL + ipAddress("dst") + COMMA + 
                "proto" + EQUAL + proto("proto") + COMMA + 
                "tos" + EQUAL + tos("tos") + COMMA + 
                "ttl" + EQUAL + ttl("ttl") + COMMA + 
                "frag" + EQUAL + frag("frag") + 
                RBRACE)
tcp = Group("tcp" + LBRACE + 
                "src" + EQUAL + src("srcPkt") + COMMA + 
                "dst" + EQUAL + dst("dstPkt") + 
                RBRACE)
```

Then I added each one back into the main parser, and gave each group a results name.

```
flowTcp = ("in_port" + LBRACE + in_port("in_port") + RBRACE + COMMA + 
            eth("eth") + COMMA + 
            Optional("eth_type" + LBRACE + eth_type("eth_type") + RBRACE + COMMA ) +
            Optional(arp("arp") + COMMA) +
            Optional(ipv4("ipv4") + COMMA) +
            Optional(tcp("tcp") + COMMA) +
            "packets" + COLON + packets("packets"))
```

(So I did 2 things here - I `Group`ed the substructures, and I gave them names.  I could have inlined the whole thing without breaking out eth, arp, etc., but I was getting lost trying to keep it all in one mother-of-all-statements.)

Now I parsed your 4 examples, and dumped out the results. The dump() method will show you the structure in the output results, and the sample code shows how to access the sub-structures using normal attribute naming (like `flowTcpValues.eth.src`).

```
for d in data:
    print d
    flowTcpValues = flowTcp.parseString(d)
    print flowTcpValues.dump()
    print flowTcpValues.packets
    print flowTcpValues.eth.src
    print flowTcpValues.eth.dst
    print
```

Giving:

```
Flows are  
in_port(2),eth(src=00:26:55:e8:b0:43,dst=bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc),eth_type(0x0806),arp(sip=193.170.192.129,tip=193.170.192.142,op=2,sha=00:26:55:e8:b0:43,tha=bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc), packets:0, bytes:0, used:never, actions:1
['in_port', '2', ['eth', 'src', '00:26:55:e8:b0:43', 'dst', 'bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc'], 'eth_type', '0x0806', ['arp', 'sip', '193.170.192.129', 'tip', '193.170.192.142', 'op', '2', 'sha', '00:26:55:e8:b0:43', 'tha', 'bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc'], 'packets', '0']
- arp: ['arp', 'sip', '193.170.192.129', 'tip', '193.170.192.142', 'op', '2', 'sha', '00:26:55:e8:b0:43', 'tha', 'bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc']
  - op: 2
  - sha: 00:26:55:e8:b0:43
  - sip: 193.170.192.129
  - tha: bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc
  - tip: 193.170.192.142
- eth: ['eth', 'src', '00:26:55:e8:b0:43', 'dst', 'bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc']
  - dst: bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc
  - src: 00:26:55:e8:b0:43
- eth_type: 0x0806
- in_port: 2
- packets: 0
0
00:26:55:e8:b0:43
bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc

in_port(2),eth(src=bc:30:5b:f6:dd:fc,dst=bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc),eth_type(0x0800),ipv4(src=193.170.192.143,dst=193.170.192.142,proto=6,tos=0,ttl=64,frag=no),tcp(src=45969,dst=5672), packets:1, bytes:87, used:4.040s, flags:P., actions:1
['in_port', '2', ['eth', 'src', 'bc:30:5b:f6:dd:fc', 'dst', 'bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc'], 'eth_type', '0x0800', ['ipv4', 'src', '193.170.192.143', 'dst', '193.170.192.142', 'proto', '6', 'tos', '0', 'ttl', '64', 'frag', 'no'], ['tcp', 'src', '45969', 'dst', '5672'], 'packets', '1']
- eth: ['eth', 'src', 'bc:30:5b:f6:dd:fc', 'dst', 'bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc']
  - dst: bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc
  - src: bc:30:5b:f6:dd:fc
- eth_type: 0x0800
- in_port: 2
- ipv4: ['ipv4', 'src', '193.170.192.143', 'dst', '193.170.192.142', 'proto', '6', 'tos', '0', 'ttl', '64', 'frag', 'no']
  - dst: 193.170.192.142
  - frag: no
  - proto: 6
  - src: 193.170.192.143
  - tos: 0
  - ttl: 64
- packets: 1
- tcp: ['tcp', 'src', '45969', 'dst', '5672']
  - dstPkt: 5672
  - srcPkt: 45969
1
bc:30:5b:f6:dd:fc
bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc

in_port(2),eth(src=bc:30:5b:f6:dd:fc,dst=bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc),eth_type(0x0800),ipv4(src=193.170.192.143,dst=193.170.192.142,proto=6,tos=0,ttl=64,frag=no),tcp(src=45992,dst=5672), packets:118412, bytes:21787661, used:2.168s, flags:P., actions:1
['in_port', '2', ['eth', 'src', 'bc:30:5b:f6:dd:fc', 'dst', 'bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc'], 'eth_type', '0x0800', ['ipv4', 'src', '193.170.192.143', 'dst', '193.170.192.142', 'proto', '6', 'tos', '0', 'ttl', '64', 'frag', 'no'], ['tcp', 'src', '45992', 'dst', '5672'], 'packets', '118412']
- eth: ['eth', 'src', 'bc:30:5b:f6:dd:fc', 'dst', 'bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc']
  - dst: bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc
  - src: bc:30:5b:f6:dd:fc
- eth_type: 0x0800
- in_port: 2
- ipv4: ['ipv4', 'src', '193.170.192.143', 'dst', '193.170.192.142', 'proto', '6', 'tos', '0', 'ttl', '64', 'frag', 'no']
  - dst: 193.170.192.142
  - frag: no
  - proto: 6
  - src: 193.170.192.143
  - tos: 0
  - ttl: 64
- packets: 118412
- tcp: ['tcp', 'src', '45992', 'dst', '5672']
  - dstPkt: 5672
  - srcPkt: 45992
118412
bc:30:5b:f6:dd:fc
bc:30:5b:f7:07:fc

in_port(2),eth(src=00:18:6e:3a:aa:e8,dst=01:80:c2:00:00:00), packets:29131, bytes:1864384, used:1.200s, actions:drop
['in_port', '2', ['eth', 'src', '00:18:6e:3a:aa:e8', 'dst', '01:80:c2:00:00:00'], 'packets', '29131']
- eth: ['eth', 'src', '00:18:6e:3a:aa:e8', 'dst', '01:80:c2:00:00:00']
  - dst: 01:80:c2:00:00:00
  - src: 00:18:6e:3a:aa:e8
- in_port: 2
- packets: 29131
29131
00:18:6e:3a:aa:e8
01:80:c2:00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. It answered all my questions and also gives the data as required. I have a small doubt, "for d in data" I assume that the flows are stored in "data" array. Could you please explain how to do this. I had stored it as "f = os.popen('ovs-dpctl dump-flows ovs-system') 
flows = f.read()". I feel this is wrong as flows[0] will be only "i" instead of a whole flow. This gives error as "pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "in_port" (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)". I'm a beginner in Python. Please guide me on how this can be done.

Comment: Using f.readlines() answered the above question also. Thank you very much @Paul McGuire

Comment: You can also iterate over the file directly, using `for d in open('filename.csv'):` - not sure why you are using `os.popen` instead of the builtin `open`.

Comment: Thanks Paul for pointing it. I really didn't know the difference between popen and open. As I had just started learning python, had copied it from the result of Google search to read a file. I understood the difference now. Great learning. Could you please suggest on what would be a better data structure to store the details such as "src_MAc-dst_MAC-src_IP-dst_IP-packets". I should run the above parsing logic for every half an hr for total 4 hrs and then store the results of each run in a database. Then search the most communicated src and dst in that 4 hrs. Please suggest.

Comment: This data is so simple and flat, I would just write it out to a CSV from your data extractor using something like: `for d in data: \    dd = flowTcp.parseString(d) \    if 'eth' in dd and 'ipv4' in dd: print "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s" % (dd.eth.src, dd.eth.dst, dd.ipv4.src, dd.ipv4.dst, dd.packets)`.  Then read the CSV into a separate Python script, using csv module, and do your min/max and summing logic there.